# properties file call in Java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, properties

I am begining with properties files in Java and I am following [this tuto](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/)

It works very well in my application except when I want a properties in a servlet.
The same function call does not give the same result if it is done from the servlet or from a "normal" class.
The path becomes wrong and I don't know why.
Maybe the path from the servlet is from the server.

```
input = new FileInputStream(filename);
prop.load(input);
```

where is the path for `filename` when I execute these lines with the servlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where is the path for `filename` when I execute these lines with the servlet?

This might help you:

```
File file = new File(filename);
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

---

Provided that the properties file is really there where you'd like to keep it, then you should be getting it as web content resource by [`ServletContext#getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

Sample code:

```
properties.load(getServletContext()
                 .getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/properties/sample.properties"));
```

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507016/load-properties-file-in-servlet-jsp)

---

### Alternately

Register [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to load Init parameters at server start-up where you can change the config file location at any time without changing any java file.

Load properties and make it visible to other classes statically.

Sample code:

```
public class AppServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    private static Properties properties;
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        String cfgfile = servletContextEvent.getServletContext().getInitParameter("config_file");
        properties.load(new FileInputStream(cfgfile));
    }
    
    public static Properties getProperties(){
        return properties;
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.x.y.z.AppServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
      <param-name>config_file</param-name>
      <param-value>config_file_location</param-value>
</context-param>
```