# Error while running a servlet (apache tomcat cannot find .properties file)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web.xml, eclipse-indigo

Any other servlet is running fine on eclipse-apache/tomcat integration.
But when I add a properties file in one of the classes, i get this error-

HTTP Status 500 - type Exception report

MessageDescription:
  The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: xyz.properties(The system cannot find the      file specified)
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
>   xyz.DatabaseConnection(DatabaseAccess.java:23)
>   xyz.HelloServlet.doGet(HelloServlet.java:22)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

Do I have to do some kind of modification in the web.xml file to let it know where the xyz.properties file exists ?

P.S - file and package name has been censored with "xyz".

Comment: Well, where do you actually keep the so called `xyz.properties` file ?

Comment: in the same package as the servlet class

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I got my answer from this page-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-configuration-properties-files-in-a-jsp-servlet-web-application

Answer (score 0):

You don not need to edit the web.xml.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("xyz.properties"));
```

This assumes that the xyz.properties file is inside the classes folder.

Answer (score -1):

I think the property file is not in the classpath. Please try putting the properties file `WEIB-INF/classes` folder and see if this resolves this issue.

Comment: Can you please make sure that the properties file name referred in code and actual file name are same ?

Comment: yup they're the same. I have used the properties files in another class, which works fine. Just the servlet class is not working.

Comment: Just a debug step: Try giving the an absolute path of the properties file in Servlet and see if it loads it properly.

Comment: @RaulGogo It was just a suggestion and not a rule and I understand that. File can be anywhere. This does not call for downvote for sure.

Comment: What I understood was that it was a rule for the properties file to be in the WEB-INF folder, that's the reason for the downvote. Unfortunately, except that the post is edited, I cannot remove my downvote.

Comment: No, I just said that I cannot remove my -1 unless the post is edited. Once you cast a vote and 5 minutes pass, your vote becomes locked. You can no longer change it unless the post is edited.

Comment: @Santosh Can you tell me how to give an absolute path to the properties file in the servlet ?

Comment: @kaustavdatta [Here is link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/file.html) to an example of loading file using absolute path.