# Opening input file using java code in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, glassfish, glassfish-3

I am using JSP on NetBeans.

In the java code, I am trying to read data from a file. First I open the file by specifying its path.

Because my code runs on a server (GlassFish), I would like to have my file path independent of the machine where it runs. Therefore, I want to start the path with the folder name that contains the file which is saved on the root of the project directory. I tried so hard to achieve that but I couldn't.

I read online and I found this way, but it still doesn't work:

```
<%

  //building the tree here.
GraphBuilder tree = new GraphBuilder("${pageContext.request.contextPath}\\src\\java\\Database\\OptimizedFullTermFile.pad");

%>
```

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: you might search for this one? `new File(".").getCanonicalFile()`

Comment: @Kevin: the CWD is not controllable from inside the Java web application. So any approach which depends on CWD is completely broken as it makes the webapp unportable.

Comment: i think i just misunderstood the Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read it from the classpath. Given that you're using the typical `src` folder representing the Java source code (the Java package/class structure), I assume that the file `OptimizedFullTermFile.pad` is placed in the Java package `java.Database` (eek, a capital in package name? lowercase it all). In that case, it's already in the classpath and thus you can just get it straight from there as follows:

```
InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("java/Database/OptimizedFullTermFile.pad");
// ...
```

As to your failed attempt: the EL `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` isn't ever going to work in a *scriptlet*. Even if it did, it's not the right thing, it returns the context path in the webapp URL which is absolutely not part of the local disk file system path, let alone the classpath. [Using *scriptlets* is strongly discouraged since a decade, by the way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202).

#### See also:

- [getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream)
- [Where to place and how to read configuration resource files in servlet based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-configuration-properties-files-in-a-jsp-servlet-web-application)

Comment: I would like to use File instead of InputStream. How can I convert your way to File? Thanks.

Comment: I strongly recommend to not do that. Such an API which requires a `File` as argument is heavily flawed. But if you really can't do otherwise, just create a temporary file by `File#createTempFile()` and write to it. Then, use that temporary file.

Comment: I did this: 
InputStream input;
input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("java\\Database\\OptimizedFullTermFile.pad");
    InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(input);

    BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(isReader); 

then I started to read the file line by line. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Apparently the file is not there where your code expects it is. Where exactly in the built WAR file is the file located? My answer assumes (based on your own attempt in the question) that it's inside `/WEB-INF/classes/java/Database/OptimizedFullTermFile.pad`. If it isn't there, but actually elsewhere, then you need to fix the path in the code accordingly to match it. Further, you should not be using back slashes but forward slashes. The Java classpath is not a Windows based disk file system or something.

Comment: When I wrote this: 

input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream ("Database/SmallOptimizedFullTermFile.pad");

it worked successfully!

my file is in the following full path:

"C:\Users\student\Documents\NetBeansProjects\geneOntology\geneOntology\src\java\Database\OptimizedFullTermFile.pad".

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code to get your directory file in project from the following code.

```
this.getServletContext().getRealPath("")+[your file path in project web directory]
```

Comment: do you mean like this: 
this.getServletContext().getRealPath("")+"java\\Database\\OptimizedFullTermFile.pad"; ?

Comment: Bad advice. `getRealPath()` will return `null` when the WAR is during deployment not expanded on disk but instead in memory.

Comment: You can use the above if your file is in your web directory.