# Path inside an web app not a direct link

Tags: java, jsf, web-applications, file-upload

in my project i am currently using direct links, these store specific files that get uploaded to the server, these locations are all in the folder of the project (fileupload)

```
destinationPDF=D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/pdf/
destination=D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/Uploaded/
fileList =D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/Directory Files/directoryFiles.txt
```

but this is not an ideal situation, as i am currently testing on multiple machines and each machine needs a different path, so i am wondering, is it possible to create a path so that it does not matter what machine it is on

Comment: What happens when you save to "filename.txt" instead of hardcoding a directory? It should load/save to current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make it externally configurable. There are various ways to achieve that.

1. Set an environment variable during server startup.

   ```
   SET UPLOAD_LOCATION=C:\path\to\uploads
   ```

   It's available as follows:

   ```
   String uploadLocation = System.getenv("UPLOAD_LOCATION");
   ```
2. Set a VM argument during server startup.

   ```
   -Dupload.location="C:\path\to\uploads"
   ```

   It's available as follows:

   ```
   String uploadLocation = System.getProperty("upload.location");
   ```
3. Set it as a [properties file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) entry.

   ```
   upload.location=C:\path\to\uploads
   ```

   It's available the usual [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) API way:

   ```
   String uploadLocation = properties.getProperty("upload.location");
   ```

   The location of the properties file itself is actually a whole question at its own, which is already answered here: [Where to place and how to read configuration resource files in servlet based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-configuration-properties-files-in-a-jsp-servlet-web-application/2161583#2161583)

Either way, you can easily reference the files as follows:

```
File some = new File(uploadLocation, "some.ext");
```