# Read external property file in java application

Tags: java, tomcat, properties

I want to load a property file  from outside the web application.The code to get property file is shown below.

```
 Properties p = new Properties();
 p.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("a.properties"));
```

I’m using tomcat server and I want to place the property file inside the tomcat server.Where I can place it in the server inorder to available it in the class path while running the application?  I don’t want to change the above code because I have to run the same application indifferent server also

Answer (score 3):

I recommend the first option. Put the *a.properties* in the classpath. Then load with:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("a.properties"));
```

This way you can load properties relative tot the "root" of the classpath. Tt's recommended to use the ClassLoader as returned by Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() for this.

Comment: if i placed the property file outside the web project for example in d drive..How can i include this path in the class path?

Comment: In this case you can use an absolute path:                   Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream("D:/absolute/path/to/a.properties");

Comment: Sory..i dont want to hard code the path ,i just want to give the property file name only...To load it from the tomcat server where i can place it in tomcat?

Answer (score 2):

There are basically three ways: The remaining portion you can see in 
[Where to place and how to read configuration resource files in servlet based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-configuration-properties-files-in-a-jsp-servlet-web-application)

Comment: i have one doubt how can i specify the propery file path in Tomcat/conf/catalina.properties?