# Configurable Values in a servlet

Tags: java, servlets

We have a small Provisioning server which only hosts servlets. Hosted on tomcat. There are few values hardcoded in the servlet which i want to make configurable or external, so that they can be modified without changing the servlets.
Can anyone please suggest what are my Options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options:

- If the values are *servlet specific*, you can configure them as *Servlet Init-Parameter*, in the deployment descriptor (The *web.xml* file):

  ```xml
  <servlet>    
      <servlet-name></servlet-name>
      <servlet-class></servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>${param-name}</param-name>
          <param-value>${param-value}</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </servlet>
  ```

  And get them using [`ServletConfig#getInitParameter(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletConfig.html#getInitParameter%28java.lang.String%29):

  ```
  getServletConfig().getInitParameter(paramName);
  ```
- If the values are *web-app specific*, you can configure them as *Context parameter*:

  ```xml
  <web-app ...>
      <context-param>
          <param-name>${param-name}</param-name>
          <param-value>${param-value}</param-value>
      </context-param>
  </web-app>
  ```

  And get them using [`ServletContext#getInitParameter(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getInitParameter%28java.lang.String%29):

  ```
  getServletContext().getInitParameter(paramName);
  ```
- Another option is to have those values in a properties file, and load values from it in the servlet. You can add the properties file to the Web-App classpath (you can put it inside the `/WEB-INF/classes` folder, or if you are using Eclipse IDE, just put it inside the `/src` folder, and load it as resource:

  ```
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("webapp.properties"));
  ```

**See Also:**

- [Where to put configuration file in JSP-Servlet Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2161583/1679863)

Answer (score 1):

Options I can think of :

1. Define them as servlet init parameters in DD(web.xml) or using annotation , if they are specific to Servlet. Look at this [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html)
2. Define them as context parameters in DD(web.xml) or using annotation , if they are common for the entire web app.
3. Define them in an external properties file . You can then load the properties file kept in the classpath.

[Java EE 7 tutorial - Servlets (Servlet 3.1)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/servlets.htm)

**P.S:** I have just given you pointers , you can get the examples of how to achieve that , easily in internet.

Comment: in case the OP is wondering, DD referred here is the Deployment Descriptor which is the web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide init params to a servlet, which can be configured in your web.xml. This tutorial should help you achieve what you need:

http://www.javatpoint.com/servletconfig

Answer (score 0):

As all said there are many ways.This is Another approach(This is what I am doing right now)

A `Constants` `Class` (Public `Static` String constants)

A `XMl`  file called `properties.xml`  for example veriosn name,branch name etc

```
<property name="version">XX..XX</property>
<property name="branch">XX.13.</property>
```

in `web.xml`

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>StartUpServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>StartUpServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>com.nextenders.server.StartUpServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

That servlet executes when you start your `tomcat`

And my `StartUpServlet`

```
public class StartUpServlet extends  HttpServlet{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        setVersion();  //I'l parse that file and assign constants.And use else where


    }
```

So with out touching the App,change properties in `xml` and restart the `App.`