# where to put custom config file in JSF

Tags: java, xml, jsf, path, config

In First Layer, I have a class library which is MyJFr and there is a method which reads myconfig.xml and returns values from this file.

In Second Layer, I have a JSF Web application and I put myconfig.xml in this project, but I can't access this file from MyJFr Project(First layer).

Where Should I put myconfig.xml in JSF Web application? I tried this before from this link: "[Where to place and how to read configuration resource files in servlet based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-configuration-properties-files-in-a-jsp-servlet-web-application)".

In addition, if  second layer is a desktop application, where should I put my config file?

Comment: *I have a class library which is MyJFr and there is a method which reads myconfig.xml and returns values from this file* which path uses your library to search this xml file?

Comment: I call readConfig method which is in MyJfr from second layer(JSF application).

Comment: I mean which path uses when is run as standalone or in your tests.

Comment: Actually, I asked this question to find solution all these problems.

Comment: You know, you're going to a doctor and saying *my stomach hurts* then the doctor asks you *what did you eat last night?* and your answer is: *my stomach hurts*, then the doctor asks *did you eat something today?* and you reply *my stomach still hurts, do something please!*, the doctor becomes kinda impatient and will try to give you some medications and asks you *are you allergic to some medicine?* and your reply is: *my stomach hurts so much*. Do you think any doctor will help you if you keep with that attitude? No? Do you think we could help you if you don't explain in detail your problem?