# Best way to extract DataBase connection settings to external file in Java EE Maven project

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, properties-file

On my local machine I am creating Java EE Maven project on Tomcat7 that collaborates with local MySQL database.

For now I have all db connection settings like (user, password, host, dbname, ... etc) hardcoded in DatabaseQueries.java directly in Java EE Maven project, but I know it is not right and I want to take out this setting from project for example to **db.properties** file, so when I deploy the project on my remote Tomcat7 server it will use different **db.properties** file with corresponing settings or if I share the project in GitHub, other people will not see my db username and password.

**Thus I have few questions:**

1. What is the best practice of externalizing the db settings from
   Maven project ?
2. Does Maven project has already build-in functionality to do this ?
3. How to be sure, that when I export a project as a *.WAR file
   it will not include this db.properties file ?
4. Is it correct to use the name as "db.properties" for this purposes ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2161054

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example , in your project add 4 folders :

1. `Your Project\src\main\resources\`

   ```
   \local > db.properties
   \integration > db.properties
   \deploy > db.properties
   \Default > db.properties
   ```
2. in pom.xml add :

   ```
    <properties>
        <param>Default</param>
    </properties>
   ```

   and

   ```
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/${param}</directory>           
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build> 

    if : mvn clean install   : classpath => db.properties(from Default)

    if : mvn clean install -Dparam=local : classpath => db.properties(from local)

    if : mvn clean install -Dparam=integration : classpath => db.properties(from integration)

    if : mvn clean install -Dparam=deploy : classpath => db.properties(from deploy)
   ```

Much better than using profiles is more extensible without touching the pom.

Comment: in which cases do I use: local, integration, deploy and Default?

Comment: could you, please, give me an example how does db.properties file show look like?

Answer (score 1):

In your case just local and remote :

```
    local/db.properties
            user=aaaa
            password=aaaa
            host=127.0.0.0

    remote/db.properties
            user=rrrrr
            password=rrrrr
            host=1.2.3.4
```

Comment: Thanks! I used your solution. The only thing for my needs I just need these two only!