# Reading own MANIFEST.MF in Java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, war, manifest.mf

I am trying to read an own MANIFEST.MF resource in a Java servlet. My situation: I have a WAR (with the manifest I want to read) inside an EAR. There are several other WARs and JARs in the EAR. A class path is really long.

I tried several ways found in the Web, including StackOverflow.

I can read all MANIFEST.MF files using

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
```

and iterate through them. However, I do not know which one is mine - I do not know even Implementation-Title since this is generated by a build pipe. (I can guess with knowledge of the build pipe, therefore I know the correct manifest is there. However, I cannot guess in a production code.)

Of course,

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
```

returns a completely wrong manifest from some other jar on a class path.

I also tried

```
this.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
```

but it returns a null.

How to access a MANIFEST.MF file belonging to the WAR containing a currently running servlet?

Comment: Which manifest attributes are you planning to read?  Many of them are obtainable with existing Java SE methods.

Comment: VGR +1,  getting version for example: String version = getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion();

Comment: Above comments are inapplicable for WAR's own manifest and therefore wrong.

Comment: @BalusC You're right.  I overlooked that he wants the .war file's manifest.  The title probably should be edited to clarify that.

Comment: Servlets run per definition in WAR. Moreover, it's already tagged.

Comment: Of course.  But there can be a manifest in WEB-INF/classes and in each .jar under WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *I also tried*
>
> ```
> this.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
> ```
>
> *but it returns a null.*

That path must start with `/` in order to represent an absolute WAR resource path.

```
this.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
```

Using `ClassLoader#getResourceXxx()` doesn't make sense as WAR's own manifest file isn't located in classpath. It's located in webroot, next to `/WEB-INF` and all. Therefore, `ServletContext#getResourceXxx()` is the only way.

Comment: This was helpful. I just don't understand how it is possible that reading all manifests by
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
did not fail as well.

Comment: You're welcome. Those come from classpath not from webcontent. Other rules apply. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-and-how-to-read-properties-files-in-a-jsp-servlet-web-application/