# Cannot load xml from from resources in war file

Tags: java, xml, maven, wildfly

My code looks like

```
public class IpIdActivityMockResponse {

  final String response;

  public String getResponse() {
    return response;
  }

  public IpIdActivityMockResponse() {
    final InputStream stream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("/response_little.xml");
    response = convertStreamToString(stream);
  }

  private static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
  }
}
```

and a `REST` endpoint as

```
@Path("/activities")
public class StealthWatch {

  @GET
  @Produces("application/xml")
  public Response getActivities() {
    return Response
        .ok(new IpIdActivityMockResponse().getResponse())
        .build();
  }
}
```

I use `maven` to bundle `war` as

```
 <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>stealthwatch</warName>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                        <directory>src/webapp</directory>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

When I deploy this on `wildfly 9` container, and hit the API

```
curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8080/stealthwatch/rest/activities
```

I see error as

```
11:52:44,611 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-18) UT005023: Exception handling request to /stealthwatch/rest/activities: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:212)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:168)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:411)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:202)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:563)
    at IpIdActivityMockResponse.convertStreamToString(IpIdActivityMockResponse.java:33)
    at IpIdActivityMockResponse.<init>(IpIdActivityMockResponse.java:29)
    at StealthWatch.getActivities(StealthWatch.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:395)
    ... 32 more
```

I also see my `xml` in war

```
$ jar -tvf target/stealthwatch.war 
     0 Fri Jan 08 11:52:36 PST 2016 META-INF/
   130 Fri Jan 08 11:52:36 PST 2016 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Fri Jan 08 11:52:36 PST 2016 WEB-INF/
     0 Fri Jan 08 11:52:36 PST 2016 WEB-INF/classes/
     0 Fri Jan 08 11:52:36 PST 2016 WEB-INF/classes/dto/
     0 Fri Jan 08 11:52:36 PST 2016 WEB-INF/lib/
   896 Fri Jan 08 09:40:14 PST 2016 response.xml
   162 Fri Jan 08 09:47:40 PST 2016 response_little.xml
   984 Fri Jan 08 11:52:34 PST 2016 WEB-INF/classes/dto/StealthWatchResponse.class
  1811 Fri Jan 08 11:52:34 PST 2016 WEB-INF/classes/IpIdActivityMockResponse.class
   896 Fri Jan 08 11:52:34 PST 2016 WEB-INF/classes/response.xml
   162 Fri Jan 08 11:52:34 PST 2016 WEB-INF/classes/response_little.xml
   873 Fri Jan 08 11:52:34 PST 2016 WEB-INF/classes/StealthWatch.class
 46968 Fri Jan 08 09:39:16 PST 2016 WEB-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar
258875 Fri Jan 08 09:39:16 PST 2016 WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.6.3.jar
1170801 Fri Jan 08 09:39:16 PST 2016 WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar
 93734 Fri Jan 08 09:39:16 PST 2016 WEB-INF/lib/jackson-dataformat-xml-2.6.3.jar
 32618 Fri Jan 08 09:39:16 PST 2016 WEB-INF/lib/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.6.3.jar
 57193 Thu Jan 07 15:46:24 PST 2016 WEB-INF/lib/jboss-logging-3.1.4.GA.jar
152036 Thu Jan 07 15:46:26 PST 2016 WEB-INF/lib/resteasy-client-3.0.14.Final.jar
161867 Fri Jan 08 09:39:16 PST 2016 WEB-INF/lib/stax2-api-3.1.4.jar
  1114 Fri Jan 08 10:06:44 PST 2016 WEB-INF/web.xml
  2285 Fri Jan 08 11:50:22 PST 2016 META-INF/maven/com.lancope/stealthwatch/pom.xml
   122 Fri Jan 08 11:52:36 PST 2016 META-INF/maven/com.lancope/stealthwatch/pom.properties
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why did you use `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to place and how to read properties files in a JSP/Servlet web application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-and-how-to-read-properties-files-in-a-jsp-servlet-web-application)

Comment: @wero, because I do not understand the difference :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
final InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/response_little.xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final InputStream stream = IpIdActivityMockResponse.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/response_little.xml");
```