# Where should I keep my .properties file in java project so that it should be outside war file. And what are the steps should I follow to implement

Tags: java, application.properties

Where should I keep my .properties file in java project so that it should be outside war  file. And what are the steps should I follow to implement

Comment: Possible duplicate of (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-and-how-to-read-configuration-resource-files-in-servlet-based-app)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the **Nawnit Sen**'s comment.

As for me I've put it in local disk file system.

Also I've granted my tomcat user all privileges to the folder.

In the `root-context.xml` file I've registered two properties files for both cases(I develop on a Windows and deploy on a Linux). You could register only one properties file

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:/path/to/application.properties" order="1" ignore-resource-not-found="true" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
<context:property-placeholder location="file:C:/path/to/application.properties" order="2" ignore-resource-not-found="true" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

Now in your class you could get the property like this

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

@Value("${someProperty}")  
private String yourProperty;
```