# How can I find image file within my Tomcat 8 java app?

Tags: java, filepath, tomcat8

In my `Java` `tomcat` application, I'm facing problems trying to get the correct file path.

Two code snippets from my Java app I need:

```
try {
        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("StaticContent/images/image.png");

        image = ImageIO.read(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e.getStackTrace());
    }
```

Second snippet:

```
DataSource fds_image = new FileDataSource
                ("StaticContent/images/image.png");
```

I have put the image into the folder:

```
src/main/webapp/StaticContent/images/image.png
```

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jozwi.png)

I have tried several ways to make sure the file path is correct, but nothing worked. Also, I put the image into the ressources folder and tried different paths but to no avail.
I assume that I choose the wrong (relative) path, but I don't know how to handle it.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Do you have a destination folder? If so, does it have the same structure? Are you packaging your program into a jar or similar?

Comment: The application will be packed to war file with maven

Comment: In your war file and in the deployed application directory on the Toncat server, is the file in the path `StaticContent/images/image.png`?

Comment: Yes, when I have a look into the folder structure of the war file, it's in there, but can't be found. I read something about context, do I have to do something in this direction?

Comment: @biro: `StaticContent/images/image.png` is **not** a classpath resource, so you need to use [`ServletContext#getResourceAsStream`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/servlet/servletcontext#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) instead. If you don't use servlets directly, please provide more details in your question.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2161054/11748454)

Comment: Thanks a lot Piotr, this works for me.