# How to read my property in war correctly?

Tags: java, jboss, war, java-ee-8

I have a problem regarding reading my property, I do it like this:

```
    FileInputStream fis;
    Properties properties = new Properties(System.getProperties());
    fis = new FileInputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(this.getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResource("config.properties")).getFile());
    properties.load(fis);
```

on the local machine, this works well, but when I deploy my application there is a problem:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content/MyProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/classes/config.properties (No such file or directory)
```

When I try to see if there is a file I need, I find it, but java can't find it.

Here is an approximate structure of my project:

src/main/java/entities/PropertyInit.java - from here I try to read properties

src/main/resources/config.properties  - here is the path to my property

Comment: Try to get the file as a ResourceBundle instead of as a resource of the ClassLoader manually. Try `ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("config");`. It may help you in this case, but the problem could be on the way you are generating the war. Here you have some [ResourceBundle Javadoc JDk 1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle-java.lang.String-). Perhaps that's not the problem and, as I said, the problem is on how are you building your project.

Answer (score 0):

Java EE is a bit more complicated with properties. Java servlet enterprise applications and it's respectible .WAR are compiled and build differently (i.e. allocation of Java classes, JSP's and other resources).

This article: [Where to place and how to read configuration resource files in servlet based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-and-how-to-read-configuration-resource-files-in-servlet-based-app) provides you with some good solutions.

The path `src/main/resources/config.properties` to your `.properties` looks correct, looking at the Java EE classpath example your code should look more like this:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(input);
```