# Set classpath in a container for a war file depoyed with tomcat

Tags: docker, kubernetes, tomcat, war

I have a war file that I deployed with Tomcat.
I have a Dockerfile and at the end I build a kubernetes pod.

The problem is that if my property files from my app do exist in the path: `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes/config/` and not in path `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes/`, so the application does not start.

Is it possible to set a classpath in Tomcat to point to a specific folder?
For example, I want to set classpath like: `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes/config/`.
I don't want to have duplicate property files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2161583/6309):

> `foo.properties` is supposed to be placed in one of the roots which are covered by the default classpath of a webapp, e.g. webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` and /WEB-INF/classes, server's /lib, or JDK/JRE's /lib.
>
> - If the properties file is webapp-specific, best is to place it in `/WEB-INF/classes`.
> - If you're developing a standard WAR project in an IDE, drop it in `src` folder (the project's source folder).
> - If you're using a Maven project, drop it in `/main/resources` folder.
>
> You can alternatively also put it somewhere outside the default classpath and add its path to the classpath of the appserver.
> **In for example Tomcat you can configure it as `shared.loader` property of `Tomcat/conf/catalina.properties`.**

[Example](https://gist.github.com/ghusta/12b50687a39bd02a88680df450a840f4):

```
FROM tomcat:8.5-jre8
 
# $CATALINA_HOME is defined in tomcat image
ADD target/my-webapp*.war $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/my-webapp.war
 
# Application config
RUN mkdir $CATALINA_HOME/app_conf/
ADD src/main/config/test.properties $CATALINA_HOME/app_conf/
 
# Modify property 'shared.loader' in catalina.properties
RUN sed -i -e 's/^shared.loader=$/shared.loader="${catalina.base} \/ app_conf"/' $CATALINA_HOME/conf/catalina.properties
```

Comment: I have only one problem, I also have log4j in the config folder and he doesn't see it. It must be overwritten with the values ​​from kubernetes, the values ​​are ok but still in the container logs I see errors related to the old log4j

Comment: @EugenGîrlescu OK, that could be addressed in a new question.