# Read .properties file from NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, properties

I'm trying to use .properties files for the first time, in which I stored some configuration information for my web application in Java, I have a class and a method dedicated to this, however, every time it returns me an exception like "FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the specified path". Here it is the code:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ClassProperties {
    
    private static Properties property_file;
    
    public static String getConfProperty(String property){
        String value = null;
        try{
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("src/java/Utilities/config.properties");
            property_file = new Properties();
            property_file.load(reader);

            value = property_file.getProperty(property);  
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        } 
        catch (IOException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

from the root folder of the project I specified the path to the files, what did I wrong?

Comment: This is a relative path (src/...) to the running JVM. I do not see anything specific why this is a web application. Anyway, first try to give the absolute path or look for the result or `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to get the current working directory of the JVM.

Comment: Then come back with more specific info about your framework, Spring, plain servlet, etc. Most webapp frameworks has utilities for reading any configuration.

Comment: You should load that [as a resource](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/78-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-netbeans). Use try-with-resources as the loading *won't* close the stream

Comment: I made several attempts: 
first I tried entering the absolute path, and it works.
Next, as suggested by @PeterMmm I ran ```System.getProperty("user.dir")``` and it returned the path to my web server, which is ```C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27\bin,``` so I assume that my ```config.properties``` file should be placed in there, unless I specify the absolute path, am I right? I thought the root folder of the project was the same one used to search for classes (which is the one I used, in fact if I need to upload a javascript file, the path I used works).

Comment: *so I assume that my config.properties file should be placed in there* Absolutely not. A properties file is a resource and should be treated as such. Web apps should only be reading the file system in special circumstances

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-and-how-to-read-configuration-resource-files-in-servlet-based-app it depends on the config you want manage.

Comment: @g00se exactly what I thought, it seemed strange to me, despite being the first time using these files. Anyway, I followed the thread suggested by @PeterMmm and it gave me cue to find a solution, so I simply modify the try like this: ```try (InputStream input = AppProperties.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Utilities/config.properties")) {``` instead of the FireReader, I'm using an InputStream, treating it as a resource as you said, and now it works fine; path was also simplified, it was not necessary to specify folders before, as the root takes everything from the src java folder.

Comment: All good. That can probably be simplified to ```try (InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("Utilities/config.properties")) {```  but I'd recommend you use root-relative resource paths as you can get caught out if you move the code to a different package. So "/Utilities/config.properties" if that first atom is at the root. Or you perhaps should call the path 'absolute' ;)