# How can i store database information in JSF2

Tags: jsf-2, jdbc

In my managed bean i need to access a mySql database.
So far i used code like this:

```
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    String username = "user";
    String password = "1234";
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

Now i have to do this in more than one bean, so if i need to change the database credentials, i have to fiddle around in like 10 files.

Is there

1. a way to store the databaseconnection
2. a way to define some variables for the whole web project

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this just for learning/hobby? Otherwise better look for JPA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should understand basic architecture of a Java EE project. It is not a good idea connecting databases in managed beans. It is really bad practice. Please have look my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16388182/892994) to understand basic architecture.

Database connections is done in Integration Tier and these classes are called Data Access Objects (DAO).

Create a BaseDao class for static connection properties.

```
class BaseDao
{
    private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    private String username = "user";
    private String password = "1234";
    private Connection connection;

    protected Connection getConnection()
    {     
          connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);    
          return connection;
    }
}
```

and extend base class to its derived classes where database connection is needed and access connection by using `BaseDao#getConnection()`.

Furthermore, it is better to keep database connections in a properties file and inject them into proper classes.

**Related Tutorial**

Read BalusC tutorial for better understanding [DAO tutorial - the data layer](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a good idea to store these kind of values in a .properties file. They can then be accessed via java.util.Properties (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

Here is a good tutorial describing how access these files and their values, I suggest you start with this: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

(More information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties)

In my IDE, I usually create a new source package /src/main/config and put all my configuration-concerning .properties and .xml files in there. If you do it this way, you need to access it like this from within your jsf application:

```
String configFilePath = "configuration.properties";

props = new Properties();

InputStream propInStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(configFilePath);

props.load(propInStream);
```

Or you can simply do this:
[How to get properties file from /WEB-INF folder in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139367/how-to-get-properties-file-from-web-inf-folder-in-jsf)